# Authorization by jsonwebtoken on Nuxt3 crashed

Tags: jwt, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt.js v3 every jsonwebtoken library fails because of package jwt where code crashes at util.inherits() and gives error "util.inherits is not a function". How cope with this problem?

Comment: Some more context is highly welcome with an actual precise package name, a [repro], or anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround, it's Polyfill Node.js built-in modules with Vite, great example is here:
https://medium.com/@ftaioli/using-node-js-builtin-modules-with-vite-6194737c2cd2